# React native deploying on iOS device stuck on Running 1 of 1 custom shell script

Tags: node.js, xcode, reactjs, npm, react-native

I'm trying to run a React Native application on iOS device. It works fine on simulator, but while running on device it takes long 20-25 minutes to run. I get stuck on Running 1 of 1 custom shell script.

I tried deleting npm, clearing watchman, resetting npm cache, updated React version, Watchman version, etc., but nothing worked. I even tried to deploy to device using commands even that is taking lot of time.

Attaching screenshot for reference.

[image: xCode output]

Comment: any solution for this?  Thanks

Comment: if found solution please let us know..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting everything inside the DerivedData folder then cleaning and building again?

Folder located at ~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData

Answer (score 1):

use this script to clear xcode data https://github.com/niklasberglund/xcode-clean.sh

NOTE: after clearing simulator data you need to run this command to be able to boot up a sim

```sh
sudo xcrun simctl erase all
```